# Doubly LinkedList traversing

Tags: c#, doubly-linked-list

I have write a C# code to insert data to a doubly linked list and to delete a node. It is working and I can traverse the list from last node to first. But I can not traverse the list from first node to the last. I can not find the mistake I have made. Following is my code.

```
class Node
{
public string data { get; set; }
public Node next { get; set; }
public Node previous { get; set; }

public Node(string data)//first node)
{
    this.data = data;
    this.next = null;
    this.previous = null;
}
public Node(string data, Node next,Node previous)
{
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
    this.previous = previous;
}
```

}

```
class doublyLinkedList
{
private Node first;
private Node last;
private int size;
public doublyLinkedList()
{
    this.first = null;
    this.last = null;
    this.size = 0;
}
public bool isEmpty
{
    get { return this.size == 0; }
}
public int count
{
    get { return this.size; }
}
public void Add(string o)
{
    Node current = this.last;
    if (this.isEmpty)
    {
        this.first = new Node(o);
        this.last = new Node(o);
    }
    else
    {
        current.next = new Node(o, current.next,current);
        last = current.next;
        Console.WriteLine("first " + first.data + "last " + last.data + "previous " + last.previous.data);

    }size++;
}
public object getFirst()
{
    return first.data;
}
public string remove()
{
    Node current = this.last;
    current.previous.next = null;
    object removedElement = current.data;
    string reEle = ((String)(removedElement).ToString());
    current = current.previous;
    size--;
    return reEle;
}

public void TraverseFront()
{
    Node current = this.first;
    string str = current.data;
    Console.WriteLine("first " + str);
    Node current1 = first.next;
    string str1 = first.next.data;
    string question = str + str1;
    Console.WriteLine(question) 
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is when you insert the first object. You need to set last to the same instance as first, as at the moment you are disconnecting the first object (this.first.next is always null), change it from:

```
this.last = new Node(o);
```

to:

```
this.last = this.first;
```